# How to mount a Macbook Pro internal ssd in VirtualBox Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, mount, ubuntu-16.04

This is driving me nuts.  I can't seem to figure out how to mount the internal sd card reader from my MacBook Pro when I am VirtualBox running latest version of Ubuntu.

Can anyone tell me how to mount it?

Thanks in advance,